# how to loop through rows and columns of a dataset

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please compress the following code?

```
Dim a as integer = 0
    Dim b as integer = 4
    Dim c as integer =4
    Dim d as integer =4

For Each rad As RadioButton In GroupBox1.Controls
    If b > 1 Then
    rad.Text = ds.Tables("questionBank").Rows(a).Item(b)
    b = b - 1
    End If
    Next



    a = a + 1
    For Each rad As RadioButton In GroupBox2.Controls
    If c > 1 Then
    rad.Text = ds.Tables("AddressBook").Rows(a).Item(c)
    c = c - 1
    End If
    Next


    a = a + 1
    For Each rad As RadioButton In GroupBox2.Controls
    If d > 1 Then
    rad.Text = ds.Tables("AddressBook").Rows(a).Item(d)
    d = d - 1
    End If
    Next
```

i am developing a LAN based multiple choice question MCQ application.
i have a form with a number of groupboxes, each containing three radio buttons.
The text property of each radio button must display one of the options of a question so that the user can choose one of the options as his answer.

The Dataset 'ds' contains the questions and answer. Each row contains one question and three options.
The questions are in column 1 and the options are in columns 2 3, and 4 respectively.

Variable a is used to loop through the rows and variables b,c and d are used to loop through the columns of a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a numbering system to name your radiobuttons(i.e. rb00), you use the row index and item index to access the radiobutton by it's name(i.e. `GroupBox1.Controls("rb" + rowindex.tostring + itemindex.tostring).text = ds.Tables("questionBank").Rows(rowindex).Item(itemindex)`).  then use a for loop instead of a for each and iterate through the table rows and nest a for loop to iterate through the items.  The iteration variables become your rowindex and itemindex. The Count property minus 1 becomes your limit.

you can loop through the groupboxes using the OfType property:

```
For Each gb As GroupBox in Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)
    'some code
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.. i would like to iterate through the groupboxes as well.                 can u please provide the code.?

Answer (score 0):

Try :
Replace

```
rad.Text = ds.Tables("questionBank").Rows(a).Item(b)
```

with

```
rad.Text = ds.Tables("questionBank").Rows(a)(b)
```